# Reset view to default after padding applied

Tags: android, progress-bar, padding

I have Progressbar view, in which i have applied

> progressBar.setPadding(300, 0, 0, 0);

Again when i touch progressBar it should get reverted to its normal view, which was before applying padding to view.

> progressBar.setPadding(0, 0, 0, 0);

tried with above padding, but view not reflected to its original size as it was before applying padding

Any suggestion how to achieve this.

Answer (score 1):

You're assuming that the padding was zero on all sides before you adjusted it.  It might be better to save the existing padding values before you adjust them so you can go back, i.e.:

```
int mLeft, mTop, mRight, mBottom;

if(isFirstPeriodEmpty) {
    mLeft = smsProgressBar.getPaddingLeft();
    mTop = smsProgressBar.getPaddingTop();
    mRight = smsProgressBar.getPaddingRight();
    mBottom = smsProgressBar.getPaddingBottom();

   smsProgressBar.setPadding(300, 0, 0, 0);
} else {
   //Reset padding values
   smsProgessBar.setPadding(mLeft, mTop, mRight, mBottom);
}
```

HTH

Comment: mLeft, right, top and bottom are set to Zero value in "isFirstPeriodEmpty"   After i apply setPadding(300, 0,0,0) its view size decreases

Answer (score 0):

have fun with it and make a custom progressbar called ToggleProgressBar that toggles between the two levels of padding? or just setPadding back to the old value?

Comment: Yes i made custom progress bar also, i set padding to previous value, like this:  `progressBar.setPadding(0,0,0,0)`  But it disappears from screen itself

Comment: `smsProgressBar.setMax(getSmsLimit()); smsProgressBar.setProgress(smsCount);
if (isFirstPeriodEmpty) {
  imgSmsProgressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
  smsProgressBar.setPadding(300, 0, 0, 0);
 }`

Comment: the whole activity... and make sure you edit your question and not as a comment next time.

Answer (score 0):

You could try to call invalidate() after you change it's padding.. `progressBar.invalidate()`